# Errors when execute `yo angular appname` in the VirtualBox Guest OS Shared Folder

Tags: node.js, virtualbox, symlink, yeoman

I am using VirtualBox 4.2.8 and running inside Mac OS X 10.7.5 as the Host OS.

My guest OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.

My development work is essentially in a Shared Folder between the Host and Guest OS.

I have successfully installed npm, nodejs, yeoman, and the angular-generator.

I was attempting yo angular appname when I come across a list of errors such as:

```
Error: ENOENT, lstat ...
```

What do I do to resolve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is basically because `yo angular appname` will attempt to create symlinks.

There is an issue with creating symlinks inside SharedFolders for VirtualBox VMs.

The solution is that

a) make sure you are running Linux variant as Host OS (Mac, Linux, etc)

b) Shut down your VM.

c) run the following command in your host OS terminal.

```
VBoxManage setextradata VMNAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHAREDFOLDERNAME 1
```

where you need to replace `VMNAME` and `SHAREDFOLDERNAME`

d) now re-run the VM and execute the `yo angular appname`. If need be remove any previously created files and folders by your previous `yo angular appname` command before re-running it.